# node.js make fails with ld cannot be found

Tags: node.js, gcc, centos, centos6

I'm running centos 6.7 and gcc is v4.4.7.

Node configure says gcc must be v4.8 or greater so from rh toolset-2 installed gcc v4.8.2. Now the `configure` is happy but `make` fails with "ld cannot be found".

In the same directory as gcc v4.8.2, there is ld-> a symbolic link to /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/etc/alternatives/ld* which points to ld -> /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/ld.bfd* .

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a gcc-v4.8.2 and nodejs-v4.4.4.

I solve this problem by set the option in the configure step '/.configure --without-snapshot'.
This will disable the v8 snapshots which may be not available to your architecture.

you can find more information in this page.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4212